# How to update mongodb array values

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x

I have a document stored in mongodb like this

```
"Fiction" : [
           {
                   "SNo": "1",
                   "authorName" : "Enid Blyton",
                   "bookName" : "Secret series",
                   "Amount" : 115
           },
           {
                   "SNo": "2",
                   "authorName" : "Enid Blyton",
                   "bookName" : "Mystery series",
                   "Amount" : 150
           }
   ]
```

I would like to update the amount from `115` to `135`.

I tried to update the value like this.

```
db.fiction.update({"Fiction.SNo":"1"},{$set:{"Fiction.Amount":135}})
```

But I get a error.

The error is

```
cannot use the part (Fiction of Fiction.Amount) to traverse the element
```

Can anyone help on this, I need to implement this to work from python.

Comment: db.fiction.update({"SNo":"1"},{$set:{"Amount":135}})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[`$ positional`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** operator in your update as this identifies the element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the its position in the array:

```
db.fiction.update({"Fiction.SNo":"1"},{$set:{"Fiction.$.Amount":135}})
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$` operator is used to iterate through the array list while updating.

Your query would be : 
`db.Fiction.update({"Fiction.SNo":"1"},{$set:{"Fiction.$.Amount" : 135}})`