# Unable to update MongoDB array of array values

Tags: python, mongodb

This is somewhat similar to my previous question [How to update mongodb array values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34605535/5039470)

```
"Fiction" : [
           {
                   "SNo": "1",
                   "authorName" : "Enid Blyton",
                   "bookSeries" : "Secret Seven series",
                   "bookName" : [{"Title": "Secret Seven Adeventure", "Amount": 115},
                                 {"Title": "Well done Secret Seven", "Amount": 135}]

           },
           {
                   "SNo": "2",
                   "authorName" : "Enid Blyton",
                   "bookSeries" : "Mystery series",
                   "bookName" : [{"Title": "Burnt Cottage", "Amount": 150},
                                 {"Title": "Vanished Prince", "Amount": 140}]
           }
   ]
```

I wish to update the `Amount: 115` to `Amount: 135`.

From the solution to the earlier question I tried it by doing something like this

```
db.Fiction.update({"Fiction.SNo": "1","Fiction.bookName.$.Title": "Secret Seven Adeventure"},{$set:{"Fiction.bookName.$.Amount": 135}})
```

but I am getting `WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })`

Can anyone tell me why I am getting like this

**Edit:**

The suggested answer works only if the index of the array is known.

But in my case the `index` of the array is not known.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating nested array inside array mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634150/updating-nested-array-inside-array-mongodb)

Comment: @chridam  The given solution is applicable only if the index is known but in my case the index is not known

Comment: As the embedded comment said, _MongoDB doesn't support matching into more than one level of an array. Consider altering your document model so each document represents an operation, with information common to a set of operations duplicated in the operation documents._ Furthermore, the solution provided an approach on how you can determine the indexes to use in the update, otherwise you are presently forced to modify your schema due to the $ positional update operator constraint - there's an open JIRA ticket for that [**here**](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831).

Comment: And iterating again: [Overembedding is the root of all evil for MongoDB](http://blog.mahlberg.io/blog/2015/11/05/data-modelling-for-mongodb/).  You really want to simplify your model.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg  Ok thanks. I will restructure my storing method